# Extra trailing slash when using sed -i

Tags: sed

I'm trying to change a few include statements in some C code for a piece of software I'm going to be distributing on a cluster.  I've gone wrong with a for loop using sed.  I would like to replace all instances of "htslib/" in between lines 242 and 246 of my code with "/opt/htslib/gcc48_1.2.1/include/hstlib/".  It sounded simple enough, so I tried it in a for loop to recurse all files in a directory and change the lines that matched.  My command was the following:

```
for i in `grep -rl 'htslib/bgzf.h' *`; do sed -i '242,246s/htslib\/opt\/htslib\/gcc48_1.2.1\/include\/htslib\//g' $i; done
```

However, I get an extra trailing slash after "htslib" in the replacement, so that it looks like this:

```
/opt/htslib/gcc48_1.2.1/include/htslib//bgzf.h
```

If it helps, the include statement started out looking like this:

```
htslib/bgzf.h
```

Thank you for any and all perspectives.

Comment: I don't think was your original command. You have `\/` between `htslib` and `opt` and that should be just `/` between the pattern and the replacement I believe. But in any case your problem there was that you included a slash at the end of the replacement. If your files all have the double slash and you want to remove it then just use the same range and `s,//,/,`. (Also this is why it is good to test `sed` scripts before running them on files in-place.)

Comment: you can use any char for sed pattern separator, for example use `_` to make it clear. i.e. `sed 's_old_new_g`.  I think it will make your script cleaner and make any typo apparent.

Comment: You do keep your files under a version control system, don't you?  And you do test your changes on copies of files before you let them loose on the main versions, don't you?  If you don't, you must love living dangerously, which is fine — but people will expect you to make basic precautions (like use `-i.bak` to make backup copies of the files rather than simply overwriting them) so that you can revert to what you had before you make changes with a minimum of fuss.  When you do something dangerous, make sure you've got your safety equipment appropriately in place.

Comment: This looks a bit like you have a path to a header file which is valid on one system but not another and you're trying to fix that by modifying the source files. It would be a better idea to leave your source files alone and to solve this problem by using the appropriate switches to your compiler to define the include path (e.g. something like `-I /opt/htslib/gcc48_1.2.1/include/` for GCC).

Comment: Perhaps some background is in order.  This is being tested in my home dir, before getting the install into puppet to push out.  So yes, version control is definitely in place, this is not in production yet, as I despise working nights and weekends.  :)  Tom: the software expects the path to be in the standard location, which isn't where the htslib headers live on our system. Puppet doesn't have a shell environment, and passing the environment (LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, CPATH) ends up clobbering CPATH. So yeah, it's the hammer.  Etan, karakfa-thanks! Very helpful suggestions.

Comment: I should add, this particular bit of software requires $CPATH to be set.